# Convert shell script to windows batch

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I'm having vollowing `bash` script, which executes another script and then executes the next argument:

```
TOOLS=`dirname $0`
VENV=$TOOLS/../.venv
source $VENV/Scripts/activate && "$@"
```

How can I convert this to be able execute this inside a windows command line?

Comment: Does it have to be batch? Batch needs to go away. Convert to PowerShell if at all possible.

Comment: The equivalent of `dirname $0` is `%~dp0` and the rough equivalent of `source` is `call`.

Comment: Unfortunatly I've to use batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it with following script

```
@ECHO OFF
SET VENV=%~dp0..\.venv
CALL "%VENV%\Scripts\activate.bat"
CALL %*
CALL "%VENV%\Scripts\deactivate.bat"
```